# How can I change 10_lupin file from read only mode to write mode?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, wubi

It is in the directory `/etc/grub.d/10_lupin`.  I am trying to install Ubuntu on my old Windows XP computer through wubi Windows installer for Ubuntu.  However, there is a bug in 10_lupin, which is a grub boot file that prevents Ubuntu from loading.  I need to make changes to 10_lupin, but no matter what I do I cannot change it from read to write mode.  So none of my changes can be saved.

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `stat /etc/grub.d/10_lupin` and the output of `mount`

Comment: The output of `mount` please. You have a read only filesystem.

Answer (score 2):

Edit the file with `sudo` privileges:

```
sudo nano /etc/grub.d/10_lupin
```

or via

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/grub.d/10_lupin
```

---

If this does not work, correct the permissions - these are the default ones:

```
sudo chown root:root /etc/grub.d/10_lupin
sudo chmod 755 /etc/grub.d/10_lupin
```

---

And taken from your comments, the file is on a read only filesystem. Therefore you can't change the file.

Comment: Thank you for the information.  It didn't help; still the file is not writable and    and cannot be saved.  at the root directory I typed:       root@ubuntu:/etc/grub.d# sudo chmod 755 10_lupin

Comment: Thank you for the information.  It didn't help; still the file is not writable and cannot be saved.  At the root directory I typed:    `root@ubuntu:/# sudo chown root:root /etc/grub.d/10_lupin`  It displayed:     `chown: changing ownership of '/etc/grub.d/10_lupin': Read-only file system`  Then I typed:    `root@ubuntu:/# sudo chmod 755 /etc/grub.d/10_lupin`  It displayed:    `chmod: changing permissions of '/etc/grub.d/10_lupin': Read-only file system`  The permissions of 10_lupin hasn't changed, still it is:    `-rwxr-xr-x`   Currently I have access only to nano editor.

Answer (score 2):

You don't. The files in `/etc/grub.d` should be writeable only by root. For example:

```
$ ls -l /etc/grub.d/10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  12K Oct 14 12:48 10_linux
```

You don't need to change their permissions and you really shouldn't fiddle with system files that way. Just edit the file as root which will allow you to save your changes:

```
sudo nano /etc/grub.d/10_lupin
```

Yes, you can give yourself write permissions by running `sudo chmod o+x /etc/grub.d/10_lupin` but that will give *everybody* write permissions to that system file. It really isn't a good idea. Just edit with `sudo` and you're both safe and can fix your system.

Comment: What's wrong with changing the permissions? if it's a one-user system, there's not a problem, surely?

Comment: @DevRobot what if someone gets access to your account? Why give them the right to edit that file? Especially since that could, conceivably, allow them to insert code into your MBR. More to the point, it's like using a tank to kill a fly. That's precisely what `sudo` is for, you don't change a file's permissions just to edit it.